# Properties Of Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The question asks if there can be a relation on a set that is neither reflexive or irreflexive. The example the book give makes perfect sense: "Yes, for instance $\{(1,1)\}$ on $\{1,2\}$."

I was wondering, if I had the relation on that same set $\{(1,2)\}$, would that be irreflexive?

Comment: Yes. In fact, the relation $\{\langle 1,2\rangle\}$ is irreflexive on every set that contains both $1$ and $2$: it contains **no** ordered pairs of the form $\langle x,x\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was an insightful response.

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is essentially a yes-or-no question with no conceivable future value.

Comment: @k170, did you really consider that bit of MathJax was enough justification to bump this very narrowly scoped, two-year-old post I was trying to purge from the system? Please look at the last active date before editing.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, forgive me my Lord. I saw it on the review queue and I added MathJax irrespective of the date. Feel free to vote to close.

Comment: @k170 Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151443/222340); your actions have undesirable consequences. In the future, please only click edit if you think the edit will make the question worthy of staying open.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, thanks for the link. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be both.

For a relation $R$ to be reflexive on $S := \{1,2\}$, then $(1,1),(2,2) \in R$. The proposed relation $T := \{(1,2)\}$ does not meet this condition.

For a relation $R$ to be irreflexive, then there must be no pair $(x,x) \in R$ for any $x \in S$. The proposed relation $T$ is fine in this regard; no such pair is in $T$. Thus, it is also irreflexive.

---

*...granted, this question is quite old, so I imagine you don't need help now. But hopefully this helps someone in the future, and, if nothing else, gets this question out of the unanswered queue.*